# Installing jdk1.7 for 32 bit windows 7, but it gives error that its not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java

Am trying to download JDK 1.7 for a 32 bit windows OS from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
It got downloaded but when am trying to install, it gives me an error that it's not a valid Win32 application. Can someone tell me what's wrong here? My OS is 32 bit.

Comment: And yes i downloaded the x86 version...

Comment: Probably the executable is corrupt. Download it again, or check the file hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you downloaded the correct version (32-bit) of the program?

It is likely that the downloaded file is corrupted. I’d suggest you to re-download the file and try installing the same.

Possible causes of this error message are:

1. File is corrupt, bad, or missing.
2. File is not designed for your version of Windows.

If the file or program you're trying to run is corrupt or missing, Windows will be unable to execute the file properly and generates this error message.

If you’re using 32-bit version of Windows 7 and trying to install a program designed for 64-bit version, you may encounter this error message.Make sure that you’re downloading the appropriate version of the program.

Comment: yes i downloaded the jdk-7u-45-windows-i586.exe, may be some problem while downloading right...

Comment: yes, download again and install

Answer (score 1):

`I downloaded the x86 version`

It doesn't matter even if you are on a 64bit windows, the x86 version should install fine.

Since yours is an `x86` version , I suggest you try to download it again and check to see that the issue persists or not.

Probably the file got corrupted during download.